# Partial is not being rendered

Tags: typo3, fluid, partials, typo3-7.6.x

I try to create and render my first partial. First i created the file "TableRow.html".

[image: TableRow.html]

Then i created an alias map for testing purposes. Whole code:

```
<f:layout name="Default" />

This Template is responsible for creating a table of domain objects.

If you modify this template, do not forget to change the overwrite settings
in /Configuration/ExtensionBuilder/settings.yaml:
  Resources:
    Private:
      Templates:
        List.html: keep

Otherwise your changes will be overwritten the next time you save the extension in the extension builder

<f:section name="main">


    <table  class="tx_troubleshooterv3" >
        <tr><td>Test</td></tr>
        <f:alias
            map="{
                masterpagez:
                {
                    0: {
                        infotext: 'This is the main page.',
                        questions:
                        {
                            0: {
                                question: 'Main Question A1',
                                pages:
                                {
                                    infotext: 'Answer A1',
                                    questions:
                                    {
                                        0: {
                                            question: 'Question B1'
                                            pages: {
                                                infotext: 'Answer B1',
                                                questions: 
                                                {
                                                    0: {
                                                        question: 'Question C1',
                                                        pages: {
                                                            infotext: 'Answer C1',
                                                            questions: NULL
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        1: {
                                            question: 'Question B2'
                                            pages: {
                                                infotext: 'Answer B2',
                                                questions: NULL
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            1: {
                                question: 'Main Question A2',
                                pages:
                                {
                                    infotext: 'Answer A2',
                                    questions:
                                    {
                                        0: {
                                            question: 'Question B2',
                                            pages: {
                                                infotext: 'Answer B2',
                                                questions: NULL
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }"
        >


            <f:for each="{masterpagez}" as="masterpage">
                <f:for each='{masterpage.questions}' as="qquestion">
                    <f:for each='{qquestion.pages}' as='page'>

                        <f:render partial="TableRow" arguments="{page: page}"/>
                    </f:for>
                </f:for>
            </f:for>
        </f:alias>
```

As you can see, i just try to pass the page from the first two questions to my partial file. Then i just try to render the infotext of these pages in my partial:

**TableRow.html**

```
<tr><td><strong>{page.infotext}</strong></td></tr>
```

But i only get the output "test" and nothing else.
Why is my partial not rendered?

**Expected Output:**

Answer A1

Answer B2

**Output (as html):**

[image: Result]

---

**Update:**

I just debugged the variable "page" but there are 4 debug boxes displayed instead of 2 like i expected?! Can someone explain this?

[image: Debug]

Answer (score 1):

Everything is working as expected. Your partial is rendered. But you are creating a rather complex array that does not fit to your iteration approaches. Your last loop

```
<f:for each='{qquestion.pages}' as='page'>
```

will e.g. iterate over this array

```
pages: {
    infotext: 'Answer B1',
    questions:
    {
        0: {
            question: 'Question C1',
            pages: {
                infotext: 'Answer C1',
                questions: NULL
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the first `{page}` will be `Answer B1` and the second will be the questions array. This is exactly the debug output you got. But neither has a property `infotext`, so `{page.infotext}` will not output anything. Try this block for your iteration instead and see the output:

```
<f:for each="{masterpagez}" as="masterpage">
    <f:for each="{masterpage.questions}" as="qquestion">
        <f:render partial="TableRow" arguments="{infotext: qquestion.pages.infotext}" />
    </f:for>
</f:for>
```

And in your partial:

```
<tr><td><strong>{infotext}</strong></td></tr>
```